# Can use provider in init state (but it gives me an error)

Tags: flutter, provider

I can use the provider in the init state, but it does give me an error. I saw answers that you need to use `listen: false` in the `provider. of` method but it still gives me this block of errors. Do you have any idea?

#### Init state code

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    final paymentViewModel =
        Provider.of<PaymentViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    // paymentViewModel.getPaymentStatus(cartViewModel);
    paymentViewModel.getPaymentStatus();
  }
```

#### Error Message

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for PaymentViewModel:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This _InheritedProviderScope<PaymentViewModel?> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because
the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be
built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is
allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant
will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  _InheritedProviderScope<PaymentViewModel?>
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  Builder
```

Comment: Is `getPaymentStatus` a future? How do you use the result of this function call?

Comment: `getPaymentStatus` is an async method, that calls another function. And that function is indeed a future.

Comment: One thing is that you can't wait for the result of any async method in initState. If you need the result for the build then you have to use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: As for the current error somewhere in your code a `Builder` widget is marked as to be rebuilt during another build is running. You can try for example [addPostFrameCallBack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) and execute the problematic logic after the current build is done.

Comment: I don't need to wait for the result. t can happen in the background. Hey that works! I wrapped the code in a `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFameCallBack((timeStamp){});` and now it has the correct behavior. Thank you!